# pip install in virtual environment / cargo metadata failed

Tags: rust, pip, virtual-environment

I want `pip install jupyterthemes` in my environment on Anaconda.

At first it said I didn't install `Rust`. But after I install and pip again, it says

```
Collecting pywinpty>=1.1.0
...
Preparing wheel metadata ... error
...
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
  Caused by: Cargo metadata failed. Does your crate compile with `cargo build`?
  Caused by: `cargo metadata` exited with an error:     Updating crates.io index

    Caused by:
      failed to load source for dependency `pyo3`

    Caused by:
      Unable to update registry `crates-io`

    Caused by:
      failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
```

There is `rustc 1.67.1`, `Python 3.6.13`, `pip 21.2.2` in my environment.